# VBA Excel AutoFilter Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting following error when trying to auto filter in vba:

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

So what i am trying to do is auto filter, search for empty spaces and delete the rows. Can anyone please help?

I have tried the standard solutions provided online e.g. option explicit etc but to no avail.

---

Data:

[image]

---

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLastRowD As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Concatenate the Row A and B
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=A2:A" & lngLastRow & "&""""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)

    lngLastRowD = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    Set Rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lngLastRowD)

    With Rng
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=""
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: the download is an exe ,downvoted unless you post the code here

Comment: I suspect that the main problem is that you are using the Worksheet_Change event. This significant action, which also changes the worksheet, should really be run on a button-click.

Comment: @Steven Martin, it was not an exe...hence Portland Runner edited my post with the same workbook.

Comment: It was an exe - you should have included the code in post yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i restored in approaching the issue from another angle:

```
Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer
i = 2

 For counter = 1 To lngLastRowD
If Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lngLastRowD).Cells(i) = "" And Worksheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lngLastRowD).Cells(i) <> "" Then
        Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lngLastRowD).Range("A" & i & ":D" & lngLastRowD).Select
        Selection.Delete
        GoTo TheEND
    Else
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print "i is " & i
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Worksheets() want the name of the sheet, like "Sheet1", use sheets(1).
Why are you creating the variable ws and rng when you only use them once
I ran this and it deleted rows with no data in column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
        Dim lngLastRow As Long
        Dim lngLastRowD As Long

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Concatenate the Row A and B
        lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=A2:A" & lngLastRow & "&""""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)

        lngLastRowD = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row


        With sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lngLastRowD)
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=""
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        Sheets(1).Range("A2").Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post. However, i am still getting the same error with your code.